# Angular js JSON data not binding from Controller

Tags: angularjs, wcf

I am trying to bind the Json data into a dropdownlist..where i wrote a service to fetch the data

```
var Divisions = assigningStudentService.GetDivisionsByGradeId(gradeId).Select(x => x.Divisions.Select(y => new  { y.DivisionID, y.Name }));
```

I am able to get the Json data out of the service but i cant bind it to the dropdownlist. I used the code

```
ng-options="grades.GradeNo for grades in Grades track by grades.GradeID" ng-model="grades">
```

My Json:

```
[  
    [  
        {  
            "DivisionID":1,
            "Name":"A"
        },
        {  
            "DivisionID":1014,
            "Name":"C"
        },
        {  
            "DivisionID":1019,
            ‌​"Name":"zaza"
        },
        {  
            "DivisionID":1020,
            "Name":"D"
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: [[{"DivisionID":1,"Name":"A"},{"DivisionID":1014,"Name":"C"},{"DivisionID":1019,"Name":"zaza"},{"DivisionID":1020,"Name":"D"}]]

Comment: Can't see the connection between your division array and the `grades` list. Could you show how your define that list?